# Requirements.txt from import statements?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have cloned in a Pycharm project, a Github repo that does not have a `requirements.txt` file.

Rather than manually identifying all modules to pip install, is it possible to create a `requirements.txt` automatically, based on all `import` statements across the entire project?

I only know how to create one when I build the project myself, and the modules are already installed, using `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: There is the corresponding action in PyCharm since 2020.1, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try pipreqs (Generate pip requirements.txt file based on imports of any project):
https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

```
pip install pipreqs
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pipreqs: Pip requirements.txt generator based on imports in project

[link](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html)
You can use it as a script: python -m modulefinder myscript.py. This way you will be able to get all the modules required.
They have a great example on the page:

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('bacon.py')

print('Loaded modules:')
for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
    print('%s: ' % name, end='')
    print(','.join(list(mod.globalnames.keys())[:3]))

print('-'*50)
print('Modules not imported:')
print('\n'.join(finder.badmodules.keys()))
```

Comment: modulefinder seems to be deprecated.